# Show Opportunity related Contacts in Custom Object Field

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

I have the next issue.
I have a custom object called 'Application', and I have this requirement:

"Show all Contacts related to an Application. Create a field on Application object, must be read only".

I solve it with apex code. 'Application' has a lookup to Opportunity, Opportunity to Account, and all my contacts have AccountId, so this way, I get all the contacts using apex code in a trigger.

But, I've been ask to change this to a Formula field in Application object.
So, my issue is next. I'm not able to get all contacts with advance formula editor, because they're not part of any object. I have no master-detail relationship.

Does any one know how can I achieve this using configuration? I should not use apex code for this req.
Thank in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it.

In formulas / merge fields syntax there's no way to go "up, up then down" (Application -> Opportunity -> Account -> down to Contacts related list). There's also nothing that would let you loop through Contacts (and display what? Ids? Names? Emails?). Roughly speaking you can only go up through dots.

You might want to explore path of "cross object workflow" rules but I imagine that when I add a new Contact to Account it should somehow "spread itself" to all related Applications? There's no straight way to fire a workflow on delete too - so you'd eventually end up with inaccurate list.

I'd say trigger was a good solution. Maybe it ws unoptimized but if it has to be in a field - tough.

---

There might be a fairly simple way of achieving that by embedding a visualforce page within Application page layout.

This should be doable with pure Visualforce (so technically there will be no Apex code ;)) 
Something as simple as

`<apex:relatedList list="Contacts" subject="Application__c.Opportunity__r.AccountId" />`

would be a good start (if you want your own layout and not a rel. list - you should be still able to pull it off with `<apex:repeat>` or `<apex:pageBlockTable>`.

There's one BUT here: it's not a field, just a display trick. Forget about using it in reports, mobile applications etc.

Another way - would it be acceptable to be 1 click away from these contacts? You could make a report "Account with Contacts", filter it by Id of one Account and later use "URL hacking" to change the filter depending on from which Application you'll click it. This link could be either a formula field or a real custom button/link. Technically - it's pure config, no apex & VF.

You can read more about URL hacking at [Ray Dehler's excellent post](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) and specifically about dynamic Reports [here](http://www.interactiveties.com/b_dynamic_report_part1.php) or [here](http://www.tgerm.com/2011/04/passing-params-to-reports-salesforce.html).

Comment: Hi Eyescream, Thank you for your comment and help.
My trigger solution uses a VF page to display the contact list. The Contacts field to show are still not defined by the client, I mean, two weeks ago they ask me Name and Phone, last week Name, phone, Address, Email... Last thursday add some custom fields... So I'm just ready to add all contacts field they require.
To add contacts, we have a VF embeed in Opportunity. As far as I know, in this VF a contact is created and associated to Opportunity Account and then is inserted.

Comment: I will try your VF approach to avoid apex code, and also the report, maybe this 1 click away solution will not be accepted by the client, but by now, I guess is the best approach to achieve this with configuration only.
Thanks a lot for your help, and just for the record, I will let you know how did this end. Best Regards.

Comment: Cool, all the best :) Remember that it's OK to answer your own question and even accept it! But yeah, messy... You "can" fit all contact fields to a large textarea field (because I imagine 255 chars won't be enough) but it's really messy and of little value. You waste storage for something that's essentially duplicated info (1 account, hundreds of applications?). Consider really challenging your client why they need it :)